# Flummoxed by 500.5 server error on IIS 8 running WordPress

Tags: wordpress, permissions, iis-8

I'm running WordPress on an IIS test server. Mod_rewrite is enabled and I've modified my web.config to support permalinks. c:\windows\temp has been modified to allow Modify access to both IUSRS and IIS_IUSRS.

Although the permalinks themselves work, I'm having an issue with broken images. But only SOME broken images. Any image I've uploaded myself via the media manager is broken. Any image that WP generates (e.g. the featured image), is appearing.

I've checked that the images I've uploaded actually exist in the location stated (they do) but they are showing up broken. When I try to pull the images up in the browser, I get that 500.5 error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I had permissions set right on the TEMP folder but I needed to add Modify permissions to IIS_IUSRS on `wp-content/uploads`